# Trying to use MVVM to add "ToDoList Task" like item to a StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So I'm making a To-Do List app with WPF and I've finished the frontend portion. Now I'm struggling to find a way of actually adding a task that has been entered in the given `TextBox`.
So far this is what I've tried (I'm using MVVM btw).
**Textbox and Button XAML**

```
<!--TextBox for adding tasks-->
                        <TextBox x:Name="tasksTextBox"
                                 Foreground="#22061D"
                                 Text="Text"
                                 Width="550"
                                 Height="50" 
                                 Margin="0 50 0 0" 
                                 FontSize="22" 
                                 TextAlignment="Center" 
                                 FontWeight="DemiBold">
                            <TextBox.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 3"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 15 0 0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Resources>
                        </TextBox>

                        <!--Add Button-->
                        <materialDesign:TransitioningContent OpeningEffect="{materialDesign:TransitionEffect Kind=FadeIn,Duration=0:0:1.6}">
                            <materialDesign:TransitioningContent OpeningEffect="{materialDesign:TransitionEffect Kind=SlideInFromRight,Duration=0:0:1.2}">
                                <Button x:Name="addTaskBtn" 
                                        Content="Add Task" 
                                        Command="{Binding NewTaskCommand}"
                                        Margin="0 20 0 0"
                                        FontSize="20"
                                        FontWeight="bold"
                                        FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                                        Width="250"
                                        Height="50"
                                        Style="{StaticResource NewButton}"
                                        Click="AddTaskBtn_Click">
                                    <Button.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect Color="#FFCFCFCF" BlurRadius="30" ShadowDepth="15" Direction="288" Opacity="0.44"/>
                                    </Button.Effect>
                                </Button>
                            </materialDesign:TransitioningContent>
                        </materialDesign:TransitioningContent>

                        <!--Grid that will display tasks user control-->
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0 50 0 0" MaxHeight="300" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                            <Grid x:Name="tasksGrid">
                                <StackPanel x:Name="tasksSP">

                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </StackPanel>
```

**Tasks ViewModel cs**

```
class TasklyViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string _taskText;


        //A command that adds a new task
        public ICommand NewTaskCommand { get; set; }

        //The text for the task i.e. the TextBox text
        public string TaskText
        {
            get
            {
                return _taskText;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_taskText != value)
                {
                    _taskText = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TaskText");
                }
            }
        }

        public string Task
        {
            get
            {
                return "Your task is: " + TaskText;
            }
        }

        public TasklyViewModel()
        {
            //Now that we have the commands property
            //We need to "create" the command
            NewTaskCommand = new RelayCommand(AddNewTask);
        }

        #region Command Methods

        // The method for adding new tasks
        public void AddNewTask()
        {
            //This method adds a NewTaskUC to the tasksSP StackPanel
            var main = new MainWindow();
            var taskUC = new NewTaskUserControl();

            main.tasksSP.Children.Add(taskUC);            
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**New Task UserControl XAML**

```
<Grid Margin="0 0 0 0">
                <Border Background="Orange" CornerRadius="20" Height="80" Width="550">
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Margin="100 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontWeight="DemiBold">
                            <!--Task Message and Time-->
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Task}" FontSize="20"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="time" FontSize="10"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <!--Rounded Check Box-->
                        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                  Margin="20 0 0 0" 
                                  FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" 
                                  Style="{StaticResource RoundedCheckBox}"/>

                        <!--Material Design Pack Icons-->
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
```

With this, I've encountered two problems;

1. When I click the "Add Task" button using the "NewTaskCommand" method, nothing happens whereas doing the same in the MainWindow code-behind works perfectly.
2. I can't find a way to make the text entered in `tasksTextBox` to appear as the text of the task. 
   Am I even using the right approach here?

Comment: Two possible issues: It doesn’t look like you’ve actually set the binding for the button’s Command property to the NewTaskCommand property. Also, that property doesn’t raise property change notifications (though you’re only setting it in the constructor, so that shouldn’t be the issue you’re having)

Comment: Oh yeah, I removed the command before posting it here. When I used that it didn't work but when I used `Click` and tried in the code-behind it worked perfectly. And the `AddNewTask` should raise a property change?
I've updated the post in the ViewModel now btw.

Comment: @Dave M 
I've tried doing it with a random `TextBlock` on the MainWindow and it works, so I believe that the problem is that the Binding in the New Task UserControl for some reason isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you don't set the binding correctly.
TextBox should be

```
 <TextBox x:Name="tasksTextBox" Text="{Binding TaskText}"
```

Button Command should be

```
  <Button x:Name="addTaskBtn" Command="{Binding NewTaskCommand}"
```

And don't forget set the viewmodel to the window datacontext.

Other tips, you can use [CallerMemberName] attribute

```
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

you can directly call OnPropertyChanged

```
public string TaskText
    {
        get
        {
            return _taskText;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_taskText != value)
            {
                _taskText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

if the binding not work you expect, you can check the output of debug on the visual studio.

-------------Update----------------

the quick way to make your code work.
Add the property below on your viewModel .

```
public MainWindow Window
    {
        get;set;
    }

    private MainWindow _Window;
    public void AddNewTask()
    {

        var taskUC = new NewTaskUserControl();

        Window.tasksSP.Children.Add(taskUC);
    }
```

Set the property when window loading or initialization.

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var model=new ViewModel();
        DataContext = model;
        model.Window = this;
    }
```

This is a quick way but not true mvvm pattern.

---------------Update mvvm  pattern--------------

If you want to use mvvm pattern, you need to change your thinking.

You should add Listbox or other itemscollection control.

Change the data template

```
<ListBox Margin="0 50 0 0" MaxHeight="300" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TaskSource}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0 0 0 0">
                    <Border Background="Orange" CornerRadius="20" Height="80" Width="550">
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Margin="100 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontWeight="DemiBold">

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Task}" FontSize="20"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="time" FontSize="10"/>
                            </StackPanel>


                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                              Margin="20 0 0 0" 
                              FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" 
                              />

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And add new TaskViewModel Class

```
    public class TaskViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public string Task
    {
        get
        {
            return _Task;
        }
        set
        {
            _Task = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _Task;
}
```

And add ObservableCollection in MainWindowViewModel.

Change AddNewTaskCommand

```
 public ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel> TaskSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _TaskSource;
        }
        set
        {
            _TaskSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel> _TaskSource=new ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel>();


    public void AddNewTask()
    {
        TaskSource.Add(new TaskViewModel() { Task = Task });

        //var taskUC = new NewTaskUserControl();
        //Window.tasksSP.Children.Add(taskUC);
    }
```

The result

[image]

Comment: This one isnt working completely. I've tried doing it with a random `TextBlock` on the MainWindow and it works, so I believe that the problem is that the Binding in the New Task UserControl for some reason isn't working.

Comment: Check the  datacontext and output window

Comment: I run your code and find you create a new main window , so it doesn't work. You should use the same window.

Comment: So I shouldn't make a new window but call the same window? Please I don't how to do that can you help? @tszzz

Comment: hello, anything new please?